# Make django work with `network_mode: host` in docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, vscode-remote

Related project : https://github.com/mjozan/docker-compose-django-react

Hello

This project is a simple app using react and django with docker-compose.

As I want to make this project work with [vscode Codespace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/codespaces) (cf this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsonline/issues/543)) , I put `network_mode: host` on the `django` service in the `docker-compose` file.

However, by doing so, django is not running anymore (the container seems to run but the browser cannot access localhost:8000).

I would like to know how I could solve this so that all services work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Host networking basically disables the entire Docker network stack; you shouldn't need it in most typical cases, and especially not for a Django Web application.  Can you remove that setting?  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Few things could be :

First check you do not have a service running on port 8000. Asumming you use Linux.

`netstat -tnlp`

If port is free try : `network_mode: "host"`

Which I use often.

If even this doesnt solve the issue, you may have to edit your `/etc/hosts` file.

Adding something like to `/etc/hosts`

`0.0.0.0         django`

Now try `django:8000`